# Trying to justify a writing in the proof of Theorem 3.8 in Basic Algebra by Jacobson

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

In the proof of Theorem 3.8 below

> If $A\in M_{m,n}(D)$, D a p.i.d., then A is equivalent to a matrix which has the "diagonal" form $diag\{d_1,d_2,\dots, d_r,0,\dots,0\}$, where the $d_i\neq 0$ and $d_i|d_j$ if $i\leq j$.

Jacobson inspired the proof by first showing D is an Euclidean domain, then mimicking the proof in the general case. I need help to justify two problems.

First, why does he introduce the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
x & s & & & & & & \\
y & t & & & 0& & &\\
& & 1 & & & & & \\
& 0 & & \ddots \\
&&&&&&&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
in the proof of the general case, where, for example, by multiplying A on the right, one obtains the first row to be $(d,0,a_{13},\dots, a_{1n})$.  My guess to this is that the subtraction by rows in one of the three types of elementary operations, namely, subtraction, multiplication, and exchange by rows, is not well defined in the general case, and the matrix above is used to replace it.

The second problem is the way he claims the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} x&s\\ y&t \end{pmatrix}$ is invertible. The following is quoted from him to show why the previous matrix is invertible

> There exist elements $x,y\in D$ such that $ax+by=d$. Put $s=bd^{-1}, t=-ad^{-1}$. Then
> $$
> \begin{pmatrix}
> -t&s\\
> y&-x
> \end{pmatrix}
> \begin{pmatrix}
> x&s\\
> y&t
> \end{pmatrix}
> =
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 1&0\\
> 0&1
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$

What I didn't get is how he can justify the existence of the inverse $d^{-1}$ so easily. However it is easier for me to comprehend this fact with the theorem that a matrix is invertible iff its determinant is invertible in the ring which he proved before and I can write follows

> Consider $s,t,x,y\in D$ such that $b=sd$ and $a=-td$, with $ax+by=d$. We have
> $$
> d\cdot det\begin{pmatrix}
> x&y\\
> s&t
> \end{pmatrix}
> =-d$$
> Thus, by cancellation det$\begin{pmatrix}
> x&y\\
> s&t
> \end{pmatrix}
> =-1$ and hence invertible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are my opinions.

In his book, he assumes that $a_{11}\nmid a_{12}$. If $a_{11} |a_{12}$, it is trivial.

If we write $a=a_{11}$, $b=a_{12}$  and $d=(a,b)$, then we have $a=a'd$ and $b=b'd$.We also have $x_1,y_1\in D$ such that $a'x+b'y=1$ and $ax+by=d.$

If $A=\left( \begin{matrix}
 a_{11}&  a_{12}&  \cdots&  \cdots\\
 \cdots&  \cdots&  \cdots&  \cdots\\
 \cdots&  \cdots&  \cdots&  \cdots\\
 \cdots&  \cdots&  \cdots&  \cdots\\
\end{matrix} \right) $,

then$$AQ=\left( \begin{matrix}
 a=a_{11}&  b=a_{12}&  \cdots&  \cdots\\
 \cdots&  \cdots&  \cdots&  \cdots\\
 \cdots&  \cdots&  \cdots&  \cdots\\
 \cdots&  \cdots&  \cdots&  \cdots\\
\end{matrix} \right) \left( \begin{matrix}
 x&  -b'&  0&  0&  0\\
 y&  a'&  0&  0&  0\\
 0&  0&  1&  0&  0\\
 0&  0&  0&  \ddots&  0\\
 0&  0&  0&  0&  1\\
\end{matrix} \right) =\left( \begin{matrix}
 d&  0&  \cdots&  \cdots\\
 \cdots&  \cdots&  \cdots&  \cdots\\
 \cdots&  \cdots&  \cdots&  \cdots\\
 \cdots&  \cdots&  \cdots&  \cdots\\
\end{matrix} \right) .$$
Since $|Q|=1$, we have $Q$ is invertible and we also have $l(d)<l(a=a_{11})$.

This is why the author introduce the matirx $$
\begin{bmatrix} 
x & s & & & & & & \\
y & t & & & 0& & &\\
& & 1 & & & & & \\
& 0 & & \ddots \\
&&&&&&&1
\end{bmatrix}
.$$

You can ues this step for the general case $a_{11}\nmid a_{1j}$. Just put $y$  at $(j,1)$, $-b'$ at $(1,j)$ and $a'$ at $(j,j)$ to get $a_{1j}=0$

Comment: Thank you. That sounds right. The usage of the matrix is quite clear now but I still feel a bit uncomfortable with the use of $d^{-1}$ in his proof as I said in the second problem. Though it is minor and does little harm, it feels better to just adopt the cancellation principle that he assumed for the commutative ring since $d^{-1}$ always gives me an impression of an invertible element and it is not necessarily true in ring I guess.